# images map on website not working

Tags: images, footer

I maintain two websites, where they use images with links in it, with img-map.
Basically, some images are in the main content and then, there's another on the footer.
I've recently realized that the links on the image of the main content work fine, but the ones in the footer don't if there is an image-map in the main content.
You can click on links on the footer, but the links are not the ones that should be, but instead, it kind of copies the code of the image on the main content, while the other's being ignored.

I've checked if the codes for the image maps are all correct and they all seem to be. I was wondering if it's more of an incompatibility of having two image maps on the same page, one in the footer.

Here's the code from the footer.

```
    <?php
    
    ?>
        <?php do_action( 'hestia_do_footer' ); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<section>
<div style="flex: 1 20%;" class="footer-nl">
<img src="https://www.animetcom.fr/animettap/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/photo_5884180074436082994_y.jpg" usemap="#image-map"  style="display: block; margin: 0px auto;">

 <map name="image-map">
 <area target="_self" alt="education@animettap.fr" title="education@animettap.fr" href="mailto:education@animettap.fr" coords="34,54,218,76" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="" title="" href="https://goo.gl/maps/ErGGSSnvsDUHNp3P7" coords="32,98,278,224" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Plan du site" title="Plan du site" href="https://www.animetcom.fr/animettap/plan-du-site/" coords="350,135,486,165" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Rapport d'activité" title="Rapport d'activité" href="https://www.animetcom.fr/animettap/wp-content/uploads/2023/04/Rapport-2022.pdf" coords="299,207,552,238" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Mentions légales" title="Mentions légales" href="https://www.animetcom.fr/animettap/mentions-legales/" coords="322,281,512,309" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Notre Facebook" title="Notre Facebook" href="https://www.facebook.com/AnimetTap.fr" coords="654,46,694,82" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Notre LinkedIn" title="Notre LinkedIn" href="https://ie.linkedin.com/company/animettap" coords="697,45,731,84" shape="rect">
<area target="_self" alt="Notre Instagram" title="Notre Instagram" href="https://www.instagram.com/animettap_education/" coords="737,46,772,84" shape="rect">

  </map>
 </div>
</section>

 <?php wp_footer(); ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: the code for the image maps as well as the method you used to insert them isn't in your question, how did you do this and can you edit this into your question? It's not possible to answer this with just the information you've provided. Use the edit links underneath the tags to adjust your question

Comment: sorry, I just added the code in it

Comment: Are you using different names for the maps? ie, is the `usemap="#{name}"` different for each image map (and matching the proper `<map name="{name}">` name)? If you're using `usemap="#image-map"` for both, that will have unintended consequences.

Comment: It was that! I didn't think about it... Thank you!